# How can make a query that returns Column Headers if the Sum of the values in the column >0

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a data range with dummy data and I want to make a query that returns only the headers when the sum of the columns is higher than 0. My first attempt has been to at least try to make a query that returns the columns for which Sum(Column)>0 by using this formula:

```
=query(A1:D,"Select A, B, C, D, WHERE SUM(A)>0 AND SUM(B)>0 AND SUM(C)>0 AND SUM(D)>0",0)
```

But I haven't had any luck. Here is a sample of a dummy table. I would very much appreciate any pointers in this matter.

```
| Dog| Cow | Cat|Horse|
|:---|:---:|:--:|----:|
| 1  | 0   |2   |3    |
| 2  | 0   |4   |6    |
| 3  | 0   |6   |9    |
| 4  | 0   |8   |12   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be:

```
=query({A:D},"Select "&if(sum(A2:A)>0,"Col1",)&if(sum(B2:B)>0,",Col2",)&if(sum(C2:C)>0,",Col3",)&if(sum(D2:D)>0,",Col4",)&" ",1)
```

[image]

Comment: great, thanks! I was not aware a query could actually be setup with IF and SUM